# How to add the version function when writing my own shell script?

Tags: shell, version-control, version

I'm trying to write my own shell script. It's almost done, so I want to add the version. For example, `foo -v` to print `foo 1.0.0`.

But I'm not sure what's a good way. I can write the version in my execute file but I have to change that each time I update the program to a new version.

I need your help :)

Comment: Good idea.  So, you have the version number *somewhere* (I mean, somewhere on the computer, somewhere other than in your head).  Where is it?

Comment: Do you mean that I can save the version number somewhere, then read that and output?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  Saving the number in only one place is probably a good idea, since this alleviates the possibility that you remember later to update in one place to 1.0.1, but forget to update in another place.  But there are a lot of ways to do this.  (I admit that, in my own, larger programs, I have sometimes entered the version number in two places just to save trouble; but this is not really right for me to do.)

Comment: Do you use source control for your development/deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the version number *somewhere* (I mean, somewhere on the computer, somewhere other than in your head), you can keep the number there (preferably, if practicable, in only one place), then read that and output.

There are of course a lot of ways to do this.  One way is by the shell's `.` sourcing mechanism.  For example, if the file `foo_version` consists of the single line

```
FOO_VERSION=1.0.0
```

then you can use this in `foo` by the likes of

```
#!/bin/bash -e
. $(dirname "$0")/foo_version

# ...

echo "foo ${FOO_VERSION}"
```

Or your `foo_version` can just consist of `1.0.0`, in which case your `foo` would simply read it as text.  And there are yet further possibilities, as well, especially if you will *package* your software for distribution.

As @JonathanLeffler observes, a more careful approach is necessary when you work with a team and/or are using version-control software (RCS, CVS, Subversion, Mercurial, Git, etc.), but if and when you start using version-control software, when you read the version-control software's manual, you will soon learn all about that.

Comment: Having the version of the script in a separate file is a recipe for having the two files out of sync -- the version of the code won't necessarily match the version of the version file.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  You make a good point, and a point I indeed had in mind when I answered.  My answer omitted the point only because I guessed that the OP was a lone, non-team programmer who had not yet advanced to the use of version control.  So, I will add your point to my answer now.  Thanks.